# How to return multiple variables in R

Tags: r, matrix, return, multiple-variable-return

```
min_value <- function(A){
  
  minval <- min(A[A!=0])
  index <- which(A==minval, arr.ind=TRUE)
  
  print(paste("The smallest non-zero value ", minval, " is located in:", sep=""))
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(index)){
    print(paste("row[", index[i, 1] ,"] and column[", index[i, 2], "]", sep="" ))
  }
```

How to print both statements out? R cannot return multiple variables :( A is a matrix btw

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide an expected output? If I apply your function, I do get both statements from the two print calls.

Comment: but you need to go to the print line and run to generate right? is there a way i can run the whole code and then the line can directly print out?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean, but for a matrix A, the command `min_value(A)` gets me two print statements.

Answer (score 1):

You could try as a list with two elements?
create an empty list inside the formula and then save the elements in the list.
I guess you can return(list) at the end then and you would have both elements in "one".